# image display according to coordinate needed in html

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have one widget of image cropping and that gives me x1 y1 and x2 y2 coordinate that user has cropped. Now my requirement is to put that cropped coordinate in some other html page.

Here is my code

my width and height of window to display is 200px 200px.
I want to fit the cropped coordinate in this 200 * 200 px window.

I have 4 coordinates, which I will get when user crop the image.

How to achieve this

Thanks.

---

I am sorry as I wrote "Here is my code" and I dint wrote anything.

I will tell the exact scenario....I am telling the user to upload the image and then user will go to cropper page where user will select the region one required then image file will get stored in server and cropped image coordinates will get stored in database.

Now I know the coordinates actually what user has selected, I mean I have x1, y1, x2, y2. and I have the complete image what user has uploaded.

Now my need is to show the user only image which user has cropped in frame of 200px * 200 px.

In other words if I say, I have coordinates and want to display image starting and ending with that coordinates in 200 * 200 px width and height frame.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to pass the coordinates from one html page to next? if so, then you are have to pass the parameters in form or some cookie or other method, when on the second page you will extract the coordinates.

Comment: I think he wants to show the cropped portion of the image into 200px X 200px box on the next page.

Comment: you are right, I want to display cropped coordinates image in 200px X 200px, I have coordinates with me in database.

I don't know the syntax of doing this. Above in my original question I added comment....Thanks for reply

Comment: not sure about html5. but is it possible to crop a image/store crop-dimensions in database without server-side code ? what server sided code you are using PHP ? Java ? And if you dont post your code at all, no body is going to help you I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while ago. I came up with the following:

you have the 200x200 div with position:relative and overflow:hidden and let it contain an img tag with position:absolute, src attribute of the user picture and width and height scaled:

```
width = user_image_width * 200 / (x2 - x1)
height = user_image_height * 200 / (y2 - y1)
```

then you need to set left and top appropriately:

```
left = -x1 * 200 / (x2 - x1)
top = -y1 * 200 / (y2 - y1)
```

If you set the corresponding css properties of the img element (and I did not make a mistake) it should show just the selected section filling the entire 200x200 div.